# Ignoring line additions when using Git

Tags: git, github

Is there any way to ignore the amount of added lines for specific files? For example, when adding `package-lock.json` to a commit, Git shows that I've added over 14k LOC, however that is obviously not true since this file is not actual code.

I'm asking this because in thr context of a course we have at uni, the contribution is calculated by the size of our commits, and it would be unfair towards other teammates to not ignore specific files.

How to count the lines for all the other files, except, for example, `package-lock.json`?

Comment: Count when? Where are you seeing the count?

Comment: @JohnKugelman, count when making a commit, or when seeing the commit stats on GitHub.

Comment: I guess you could use `.gitattributes` to set it as binary, but line count is a really bad way to measure how much someone contributes to code anyway in general.

Comment: Easiest way might be to segregate those files to their own separate branch and merge only for use.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Stop measuring performance by counting lines of code.

---

git does not provide a LOC number.

If you're after a quick git metric that could be used as a **proxy** of how active participants are then you can use `git shortlog`

```
git shortlog --summary --numbered
```

> -n
>   --numbered
>
> Sort output according to the number of commits per author instead of author alphabetic order.
>
> -s
>   --summary
>
> Suppress commit description and provide a commit count summary only.

---

If you're after code metrics for your solution and work with Visual Studio you can see [Code metrics values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/code-metrics-values?view=vs-2019).

> Lines of Code - Indicates the approximate number of lines in the code. The count is based on the IL code and is therefore not the exact number of lines in the source code file. A high count might indicate that a type or method is trying to do too much work and should be split up. It might also indicate that the type or method might be hard to maintain.
>
> Note
>
> The command-line version of the code metrics tool counts actual lines of code because it analyzes the source code instead of IL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that this rule is enforced by the course coordinator, it's not something we came up with.